# compile my source code using iphone sdk without xcode ide

Tags: iphone

I hope to compile my source codes using iphone sdk, but I do not hope to compile in xcode.
Is it possible?
And how to do if I hope to get the XCode compiling scripts?

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

interdev

Comment: are you using a Mac? I'm assuming that you're not, but it's not clear. If you are on a Mac, why not compile w/ XCode?

Comment: Perhaps he is automating things or using a CI server?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the xcodebuild tool.

man xcodebuild for more information.

```
xcodebuild -configuration "$CONFIGURATION" -sdk $SDK
```

Answer (score 0):

Was curious myself and searched for it. Looks like `gcc` with the `-framework Foundation` set will compile the application for you. ( http://www.w3style.co.uk/compiling-objective-c-without-xcode-in-os-x )

I haven't tried this yet though.